# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener doesn't work for my another ListView

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth, onitemclicklistener

I have two `ListView`s for discovered and paired Bluetooth devices in same XML file but `OnItemClickListener` only reacts to clicks on my paired devices `ListView`. I wonder should I have own `OnItemClickListener` for both `ListView`s. Actually I tried that option without success but maybe I just made some mistake there.

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener discoveredDeviceClickListener
        = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

        // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
        cBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        // Start new activity and send the MAC address
        Intent BluetoothTransferIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BluetoothTransferActivity.class);
        BluetoothTransferIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

        startActivity(BluetoothTransferIntent);
        // Set result and finish this Activity
        //setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, BluetoothTransferIntent);
    }
};

pairedBluetoothDeviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_device_list);
pairedBluetoothDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(discoveredDeviceClickListener);

discoveredBluetoothDeviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.discovered_device_list);
discoveredBluetoothDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(discoveredDeviceClickListener);

discoveredBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList();
discoveredBluetoothAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, discoveredBluetoothDevices);

pairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList();
pairedBluetoothAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedBluetoothDevices);

discoveredBluetoothDeviceList.setAdapter(discoveredBluetoothAdapter);
pairedBluetoothDeviceList.setAdapter(pairedBluetoothAdapter);
```

And XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bluetooth"
tools:context="com.example.jake.bluetooth.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/discovered_device_list"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>

 <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/paired_device_list"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
     android:divider="#000000"
     android:dividerHeight="1dp" >

 </ListView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SetOnBluetooth"
    android:id="@+id/SetOnBluetoothButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="133dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SetOffBluetooth"
    android:id="@+id/SetOffBluetoothButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SetOnBluetoothButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Query"
    android:id="@+id/QueryButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ReceiveButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ReceiveButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ReceiveButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/DiscoverDevices"
    android:id="@+id/DiscoverDevicesButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SetOffBluetoothButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Connect"
    android:id="@+id/ConnectButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SetOnBluetoothButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/SetOnBluetoothButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Send"
    android:id="@+id/SendButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SetOffBluetoothButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SetOffBluetoothButton"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Receive"
    android:id="@+id/ReceiveButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SetOnBluetoothButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/SetOnBluetoothButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Visible"
    android:id="@+id/VisibleButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/DiscoverDevicesButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Exit"
    android:id="@+id/ExitButton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/VisibleButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Big thanks in advance!

Edit: I don't know if this help but Android Studio's Android Monitor gives this message after I have pressed item in the `ListView`: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 0):

Yes u have to use two OnClickListener since you have to use two list views.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But I am still not able to get it register the clicks on the discovered device `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

Your not writing the code in proper order. I rewrote it .Once try it

```
pairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList();
pairedBluetoothAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedBluetoothDevices);
pairedBluetoothDeviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_device_list);
pairedBluetoothDeviceList.setAdapter(pairedBluetoothAdapter);
pairedBluetoothDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(discoveredDeviceClickListener);

discoveredBluetoothDeviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.discovered_device_list);
discoveredBluetoothDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(discoveredDeviceClickListener);
discoveredBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList();
discoveredBluetoothAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, discoveredBluetoothDevices);
discoveredBluetoothDeviceList.setAdapter(discoveredBluetoothAdapter);

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener discoveredDeviceClickListener
    = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

    // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
    cBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
    String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
    String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

    // Start new activity and send the MAC address
    Intent BluetoothTransferIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BluetoothTransferActivity.class);
    BluetoothTransferIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

    startActivity(BluetoothTransferIntent);
    // Set result and finish this Activity
    //setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, BluetoothTransferIntent);
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that didn't help